# Setting field value to url of newly created Document in workflows

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2010

Trying to set column in a list to the url pointing to the newly created document (via "Create Item" Action). What should be the column type - string or Hyperlink? Also which column from the Document Library would contain the right url?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink!
Dont understand your second question "Also which column from the Document Library would contain the right url?"

Comment: Thanks for the information. Re second question - which column in the document library would contain the url to the newly created document.